# PyQt5 Urllib Dropping Output

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm running a PyQt5 UI that adds IP addresses through REST APIs.  When sending operations to my worker Thread (runs a few for loops, and runs a few functions within those loops), whenever I get an exception thrown within the code...it will not print the exact error from json.loads.

My main goal is to get the exact err.read() of the the 4xx or 5xx error I receive, so to tell the user what exactly happened (the 4xx and 5xx errors will output, just not the json.loads(err.read()).)

```
def patch_object_group (f):
    self.api_path = "/api/objects/networkobjectgroups/EXT-SFTPALLOWED/"
    self.req = urllib.request.Request(str(server) + self.api_path, json.dumps(self.patch_data_group).encode('utf-8'), headers, method="PATCH") #Default Method is Post
    self.base64string = base64.encodestring(('%s:%s' % (username,password)).encode()).decode().replace('\n', '')
    self.req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % self.base64string)
    try:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(self.req)#Had to add .request between the url for python 3.
        self.status_code = f.getcode()
        # print("Status code is {}.".format(self.status_code))
        if self.status_code == 204:
            print ("The following object was added to the group successfully: {}".format(self.patch_data_group["members.add"][0]["value"]))
            jsonoutputlist.append(self.patch_data_group)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as err: #Python3 requires urllib.error.HTTPError to work.
        print ("Error received from server: {}.  HTTP Status code: {}".format(err.reason, err.code))
```

In this try statement, with logging and Printouts the code never makes it into the "if" statement...and it appears json.loads(err.read) doesn't actually read the error.

```
try:
    json_error = json.loads(err.read)
    if json_error: #Doesn't make it into the if statement when error is received.
        print (json.dumps(json_error,sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
except ValueError:
    pass
finally:
    if f:  f.close()
    return (f)
```

I'm using the following in my main UI (not worker thread) to Emit all stdout's to the UI textbox.

```
class EmittingStream(QtCore.QObject):
    textWritten = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def write(self, text):
        self.textWritten.emit(str(text))
    def flush(self):
        pass
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after further testing!  json_error was receiving the error as bytes and not a str.  I found that in my code I was just passing the ValueError...not error handling appropriately.

```
except ValueError:
    pass
```

I added in the following:

```
except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))
    pass
```

This allowed me to see the exact error was a TypeError.

Found my json_error was actually passing as a byte and not a string.  Added .decode() to my code and now it outputs the exact error.

```
json_error = json.loads(err.read().decode())
```